# How to read multiline string as file stream in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

How can we read multiline string as a file stream in python?

I have tried this:

```py
import io

mystr = """
# comment line
line 1
line 2
line 3
"""

myfile = io.StringIO(mystr)

with open(myfile) as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        print(line)
```

But this fails.

Comment: You don't need to call `open` - change it to `with myfile as fi:` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres already an great answer. But, if you want to skip the commented lines you can do this:

```py
import io
import itertools

mystr = """
# comment line
line 1
line 2
line 3
"""

with io.StringIO(mystr) as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            print(line)
```

Or, if you want fancier:

```py
with io.StringIO(mystr) as fi:
    for line in itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: line.startswith("#"), fi.readlines()):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) already implements *Base class for text I/O* (`TextIOBase`) - no need for additional `open(...)`:

```
myfile = io.StringIO(mystr)

with myfile as fi:
    for line in fi:
        # line = line.strip()   # uncomment to strip trailing newline
        print(line)
```

Comment: also no need for `.readlines()`

Comment: OP may want to add a `.strip()` in there, depending on what their actual desired output is

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yep, copy-pasted initial code, fixed. Thanks